# How to fix stuck javascript counter in Revolution-slider

Tags: javascript, revolution-slider

I try to add a counter (that I found on this forum) in the 7th slide of my revslider.

http://www.protheine.com/odcnew/

[Counter screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpXgM.png)

The counter works in local on a normal html page, but once added to revslider it only shows the result and don't countup.

Inserted HTML as text in slider :

```js
var START_DATE = new Date("January 6, 2019 11:40:00"); // put in the starting date here
var INTERVAL = 5; // in seconds
var INCREMENT = 2; // increase per tick
var START_VALUE = 1400000; // initial value when it's the start date
   var count = 0;
    
window.onload = function() {
var msInterval = INTERVAL * 1000;
var now = new Date();
count = parseInt((now - START_DATE) / msInterval) * INCREMENT + START_VALUE;
document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = count;
setInterval("count += INCREMENT; document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = count;", msInterval);
}
```

```html
<div id="counter"></div>
```

Is here a may to make it move like it should do ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you have js error on your page suggesting that count is not available its probably becasue you are using strange setInterval sytax with string as first parameter.
If first argument is a string it is evaluated in global context where you dont have access to count variable because it is wrapped with onload handler.

Let try change it to:

```
setInterval(function(){
    count += INCREMENT;
    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = count;
}, msInterval);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it's indeed much clearer, and it works !